# Cannot enter slash ('/') in contenteditable for webextension

Tags: html, contenteditable, firefox-addon-webextensions

Consider the following HTML document (`panel.html`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <meta charset="utf-8"/> </head>
<body> <div contenteditable="true">foo</div> </body>
</html>
```

When accessed as ordinary HTML document the "foo" string is editable and in particular you can add slashes like so: "fo//o".

However when I load this document as a devtools panel in a webextension in Firefox 74 I'm not able to enter slashes. To be clear I can enter any other character including Unicode characters. Just no slashes. <s>Not even via copy and paste.</s> (Edit: Copy and paste seems to work now. Maybe the resaon was my own incompetence.) Is that behavior intended or a bug? And independently from that how can I work around this?

```js
browser.devtools.panels.create(
    "Cool Panel",
    "icons/logo-48.png",
    "panel.html"
)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Firefox. There was a [similar bug](https://crbug.com/923338) in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sounds similar indeed. I guess I'm just going to file a bug report and use the keydown event to work around this for now. I'm posting an actual answer as soon as I'm getting confirmation on Firefox's bug tracker.

Comment: Bug filed:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1633269